# end() function

Tags: jquery

The `end()` function in jQuery reverts the element set back to what it was before the last destructive change, so I can see how it's supposed to be used, but I've seen some code examples, eg: [on alistapart](http://alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms) *(which were probably from older versions of jQuery - the article is from 2006)* which finished every statement off with `.end()`. eg:

```
$( 'form.cmxform' ).hide().end();
```

- Does this have any effect?
- Is it something I should also be doing?
- What does the above code even return?

Answer (score 5):

That `end()` doesn't do anything. There's no point to coding like that. It will return `$('#myBox')` -- the example is pretty poor. More interesting is something like this:

```
$('#myBox').show ().children ('.myClass').hide ().end ().blink ();
```

Which will show `myBox`, hide the specified children, and then blink the box. There are more interesting examples here:

http://simonwillison.net/2007/Aug/15/jquery/

such as:

```
$('form#login')
    // hide all the labels inside the form with the 'optional' class
    .find('label.optional').hide().end()
    // add a red border to any password fields in the form
    .find('input:password').css('border', '1px solid red').end()
    // add a submit handler to the form
    .submit(function(){
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');
    });
```

Comment: oh yeah, i mean, i understand that use of it, i'm just wondering if there was some of reasoning behind code like the example.

Comment: yeah that's what I thought... that's pretty much exactly the code I got from alistapart (http://alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms). ALA is usually pretty good with their techniques, so I was wondering if there was something I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

From [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/end/) there is an example:

```
$('ul.first').find('.foo')
  .css('background-color', 'red')
.end().find('.bar')
  .css('background-color', 'green')
.end();
```

and after it a clarification:

> The last end() is unnecessary, as we are discarding the jQuery object immediately thereafter. However, when the code is written in this form, the end() provides visual symmetry and a sense of completion —making the program, at least to the eyes of some developers, more readable, at the cost of a slight hit to performance as it is an additional function call.